# nginx fails to start

Tags: nginx

We are running into the following error when we try to start Nginx (on Ubuntu)
""
Starting nginx "/usr/local/nginx/on"  "No such file or directory"
""

It started showing up all of a sudden.

Did anyone run into this scenario?
Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should this be on ServerFault?

Comment: Does the "No such file or directory" appear in the shell or in the nginx log file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server administration. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is probably that you a something like `access_log on;` in one of your config-files.
Just change `on` to the `path/to/your/logfile` :)

Comment: **```nginx -t```**
To see log file simply write this.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem you are running the Nginx provided by apt-get because that one would be started with "sudo /usr/sbin/nginx". Is you nginx binary really placed in "/usr/local/nginx/on"? Where did you get it from in this form?

Comment: `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx` helped me! thnks..

Comment: In my case it is placed in `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx` and I get that error: `nginx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory` What is wrong????

Answer (score 3):

My ubuntu install uses service to start nginx:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

If the error message appears in the log file and not the shell, then I think the missing file might be something included by nginx.conf or by another conf file. Did you add any configuration or remove any configuration recently?

If it appears in the shell, then chances are something is broken in your nginx install.

Answer (score 0):

I've got nginx installed on my Ubuntu server, and there's no `/usr/local/nginx/on`.

I start it with `/etc/init.d/nginx on`.

Comment: this also did the job for me
`/etc/init.d/nginx start`

Answer (score 0):

you just need co create directory /usr/local/nginx writable to nginx process

Comment: I don't think nginx needs write permissions to that directory. That seems to be a place for binaries, not anything writeable. /var/log/nginx should be the only place writeable to nginx, unless you need to be able to upload files or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem ("No such file or directory" mgs), and the reason is following - the file **has wrong carriage return symbols**. As simple as that! I'm on Windows, my text editor inserted CR+LF for carriage return, while Unix accepts only LF, otherwise it cannot parse the file.

You can read more details how to convert your bash script from Windows to Unix here - http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html